# How to avoid clicking twice on dynamic created elements to fire lightbox()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, events

I am creating dynamic content of markers in Google Maps - using `Infobox plugin` (instead of `InfoWindow`). I have dynamic content of each marker, which is shown after clicking on the marker. Inside Infobox there is an image, which is created dynamically, so I am calling `on` method to cause `lightbox` will be working on those elements.

But I need to click twice on the image (first time it will init all dynamic `a[rel*=lightbox]`, and on second click it will show big image in the lightbox).

Why is this happening and how I can avoid this?

```
var ib = new InfoBox({
    content: "",
    disableAutoPan: false,
    maxWidth: 320,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-160, 0),
    zIndex: null,
    boxStyle: {
        color: "#fff",
        background: "url('../i/1px_tmavsi.png') repeat",
        width: "320px",
        padding: "0px",
        fontSize: "14px"
    },
    closeBoxMargin: "0px",
    closeBoxURL: "",
    enableEventPropagation: true,
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
});

google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', (function() {
    return function() {
        ib.setContent("<div class='ib_content'><a href='/i/big.jpg' rel='lightbox'><img src='/i/small.jpg' /></a></div>");
        ib.open(map, marker);
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(GPS[0], GPS[1]));

        //$(document).on("focusin", ".ib_content", function(e) {
        $(document).on("click", "a[rel*=lightbox]", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("a[rel*=lightbox]").lightBox();
        });
    }
})());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue, just adding listener to the `ib` (Infobox), and when its changed, `lightbox` is reinitialized for new `images`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(ib, 'domready', function() {
  $("a[rel*=lightbox]").lightBox();
});
```

And the other code is the same:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', (function() {
    return function() {
        ib.setContent("<div class='ib_content'><a href='/i/big.jpg' rel='lightbox'><img src='/i/small.jpg' /></a></div>");
        ib.open(map, marker);
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(GPS[0], GPS[1]));
    }
})());
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing I have idea for this :)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', (function(i) {
    return function() {
        ib.setContent("<div class='ib_content'><a href='/i/big.jpg' rel='lightbox' id='lightbox_"+i+"'><img src='/i/small.jpg' /></a></div>");
        ib.open(map, marker);
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(GPS[0], GPS[1]));

        $("#lightbox_"+i).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            $("#lightbox_"+i).lightBox();
        });
    }
})(i));
```

**Update**
see my example
http://jsfiddle.net/rbss1ej0/14/

Comment: You can try it here: `http://www.cyklomapy.sk/trasa/732f2d264baecec80e8fe3820beb01adc4b1a13e`, there are two track points (blue icons), click on one of them, and there is an image, which I need to use as `lightbox`.

Comment: It cant work, because first time you click on the image, it will init lightbox with `$("#lightbox_"+i).lightBox()`, and only when you click second time, then it will show big photo in the lightbox .

Comment: This I tried before, you cant do it like this on dynamic created elements. This will ignore lightbox and open big image in whole browser tab.

Comment: You cant use `.click()` on dynamic created elements. Your solution is not working.

Comment: Your example is doing something much different. I am changing dynamically the content of the `Infobox`, and then trying to reinitialize `lightbox` on it. The solution is simple - to use `google.maps.event.addListener(ib, 'domready', function()...`